# laravel-mix + sass + glob wildcard imports

Tags: webpack, sass, glob, laravel-mix

### Background: SASS glob import with gulp

In the past we used gulp and [node-sass-globbing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass-globbing) to compile our SASS files.

This allowed a wildcard syntax like this:

```
@import "path/*.scss";
```

It also supports multiple levels of nested import.

### Backgorund: SASS glob import with pure webpack

There is a number of solutions available for webpack. E.g. [import-glob-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/import-glob-loader
These solutions typically ship with config instructions for pure webpack.

The config will look a bit different in laravel-mix, but it can be made to work.

Unfortunately, none of them support nested glob import.

### Q1: SASS glob import with laravel-mix

We are now using a product which ships with laravel-mix by default. We could turn back to pure webpack or to gulp, but we want to give laravel-mix a chance.

The "config" file in laravel-mix is quite different from what we would find with pure webpack.

So I am not sure if the 'import-glob-loader' would work with laravel-mix, and if so, how to apply the settings.

There is also https://github.com/MohamedLamineAllal/laravel-mix-glob, but it seems more about js than SASS. I don't see any code snippet there about SASS imports.

### EDIT: Found the answer for Q1.

In the laravel-mix config:

```js
mix
  [..]
  .webpackConfig({
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.scss/,
          loader: 'import-glob-loader'
        }
      ]
    }
  });
```

Credits: https://gist.github.com/arshad/4cade23e5a7f0ac800fa50b691a85568

### Q2: glob solution that works in imported files.

main.scss:

```
@import my/*.scss
```

my/hello.scss:

```
@import ../my2/*.scss
```

my2/hello2.scss:

```
body {
  border: 10px solid green;
}
```

This works with `node-sass-globbing` with gulp / node-sass.

But is there a solution for laravel-mix?

### Related questions

[Laravel Mix global sass loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54862714/laravel-mix-global-sass-loader)
This is also about laravel-mix + sass glob, but it does not give as much detail about "packages we looked at so far". And it has no answer yet.

(At worst, if we close this as duplicate, it might give the other some link juice..)

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Answer to Q1 worked for me, along with installing `npm install --save-dev import-glob-loader`